Clarification on electric fields and potentials inside conductors
I'm doing the following problem from the 2014 USA physics olympiad:

Everything makes sense until question iv.
The official solution is the following:

I understand everything till they say the potential decrease with a shifted 1/r inside the shell. How do we know it is exactly a 1/r relationship? It would be the case if there was only the +q charge, but now the electric field inside the shell is also affected by the charge distribution on the inner and outer surfaces of the shell. Hence the +q changes the potential by 1/r, but how do we know the neutral conducting shell does the same? How would you prove that it is indeed a 1/r relationship and not something more complicated?
Moreover, am I right in sayin that the electric potential must be continuous at the surface of the conductor, because even though the E field is not continuous if we image to move a little distance dx over the surface of the conductor the work done by the non continuous E field is still negligible, hence the potential doesn't abruptly change?

The answer to your question can be obtained by using the Gaussian law. It states that the integral of the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ over a surface $\mathbf{A}=A\mathbf{n}$ is proprtional to the enclosed charge $q$.
$$\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}=\int_{\partial A}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}$$
For your question you can solve this integral by assuming that the electric field is pointing in radial direction $\mathbf{E}=E\mathbf{r}/r$. If you integrate in sperical coordiantes you can simply solve the integral for a given radius $r$. This results in
$$E_i=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\,\, .$$
The index $i$ stands for the two different regions in your question ($x<a$ and $x>b$). You can obtain the potential $\Phi$ by using $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla \Phi$. This gives
$$\Phi_i = \frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon r}+C_i$$
The constants $C_i$ are important. They ensure that the potential is continous (this is necessary, otherwise the electrical field is not well defined). We can also use that the potential between $a$ and $b$ is constant, since the shell is conducting. Gaussian law is still vaid here, because in reality there would be some induced charges on the surface of the shell. Lastly, we can define $\Phi (r=\infty)=0$. With all this information one can calculate the $C_i$ and draw the sketch in your question.

Due to the spherical symmetry, it is convenient to use Gauss' law in integral form with spherical closed surfaces.
For $0 \lt r \lt a$ the total charge enclosed by the sphere of radius $r$ is $q$, so Gauss' law and spherical symmetry implies that $\mathbf{E} = E(r)\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is radial and $4\pi r^2 E(r) = \frac{q}{\varepsilon_0}$, so we have $$\mathbf{E} = \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}\quad\text{for }0 \lt r \lt a$$
For $a \lt r \lt b$ we must have $\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{0}$ since we are in the interior of a perfect conductor.
For $r \gt b$, the total charge enclosed by the sphere of radius $r$ is again $q$ because the conductor is neutral (it will accumulate some negative surface charge on the interior surface $r = a$, but it will be cancelled by positive surface charge on the outer surface $r = b$). So we also have
$$\mathbf{E} = \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}\quad\text{for }b \lt r \lt \infty$$
The electric potential is defined so as to satisfy $\mathbf{E} = -\nabla\Phi$.
Due to spherical symmetry, we also expect the electric potential to be a function of $r$ only, so we have $\mathbf{E} = -\frac{d\Phi}{dr}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$. So we have $-\frac{d\Phi}{dr} = E(r)$ or $\Phi(r) = -\int E(r)\,dr + C$ for some constant $C$. If we define the electric potential $\Phi$ so that $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}\Phi(r) = 0$ then we must have
$$\Phi(r) = \int_r^\infty E(r)\,dr$$
(since $r$ is in the lower bound, there is an extra minus sign that cancels the minus sign in $-\int E(r)\,dr$).
Since $E(r)$ is a bounded, integrable function, $\Phi$ is continuous, including at $r = a$ and $r = b$.
When $r \geq b$ we have
$$\Phi(r) = \int_r^\infty E(r)\,dr = \int_r^\infty \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^2}\,dr = \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}$$
When $a \leq r \leq b$ we have
$$\Phi(r) = \int_r^\infty E(r)\,dr = \int_r^b 0\,dr + \int_b^\infty \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^2}\,dr = \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 b}$$
When $0 \lt r \leq a$ we have
$$\Phi(r) = \int_r^\infty E(r)\,dr = \int_r^a \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^2}\,dr + \int_a^b 0\,dr + \int_b^\infty \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r^2}\,dr$$$$ = -\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 a} + \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r} + \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 b} = \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r} - \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b}\right)$$
